# Sumas dentro de un rango en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que consiste en sumar números dentro del rango 20-30, pero al querer correr mi programa, me marca error en la línea 22, chequé el código y según yo no hay error alguno. ¿Me podrían decir en qué me estaría equivocando? Por favor. Adjunto código.

```
/* Sumas */
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
  int numero,suma=0;  
    
    do{
      
     cout<<"Escribe un número: ";cin>>numero; 
      
      if(numero>0){
      
      suma+=numero;
      
      }
      
    }while(((numero>20)||(numero<30))&&(numero!0));
    
    cout<<"\nLa suma es: "<<suma<<endl;
    
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `(numero!0)`, no sera `(numero!=0)`?

Comment: El `getch` no sé llegará a ejecutar si está luego del `return`.

Comment: @Pablochaches cierto, creo que ese era el error, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Esta línea:

```
}while(((numero>20)||(numero<30))&&(numero!0));
```

Debería estar así:

```
}while( numero > 20 && numero < 30 );
```

Primero, `numero!0` no significa nada. El operador `!` está negando el 0, lo que lo convierte automáticmente en 1, y `numero1`, siendo `1` el resultado de una operación, no es algo que tenga sentido en C++. Para comprobar una desigualdad hay que usar `!=`

Si luego nos fijamos en el resto de la comparación

```
(numero>20)||(numero<30)
```

Está claro que cualquier número que elijas va a ser mayor de 20 y/o menor de 30. Es decir, esa comparación arrojará un resultado verdadero para cualquier número.

Si quieres restringir al rango 20-30 entonces sucede que el número debe ser mayor de 20 y menor de 30, es decir:

```
(numero > 20 && numero < 30)
```

Para finalizar, piensa que el número no deberías sumarlo hasta que no hayas verificado que dicho número está en el rango esperado. Esto en el código lo puedes expresar así:

```
int suma = 0;
int numero = 0;

do{
   suma += numero;
   cout<<"Escribe un número: ";cin>>numero; 
}while( numero>20 && numero<30);
```

Es decir, sumas el número en la siguiente iteración, una vez que dicho número ha sido validado.

O también podrías mover la condición al interior del bucle `while`:

```
int suma = 0;

while(true)
{
    cout<<"Escribe un número: ";cin>>numero; 
    int numero;
    cin >> numero;
    if (numero>20 && numero<30)
        suma += numero;
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo corregí y funcionó